Unity - how to avoid spurious in-world input triggers by button/key when closing Pause Menu
I'm using Unity's tradition Input (not the new Input System), and I have a Pause Menu which mostly works correctly (timeScale to 0, I can navigate with keyboard or gamepad, etc).
The one thing I'm trying to debug is... if I close the Pause menu by pressing the gamepad (A) button while my "Resume Game" button is selected, then the press of the (A) button is ALSO picked up by the game itself in the instant that the game becomes unpaused, and therefore a player action can be spuriously initiated.
I need to keep the game world from receiving the input event that "caused the unpause", either if there's some way to "eat" that input so that it won't be transmitted to other game objects / components. Or by otherwise somehow cleanly detecting that the game has just become unpaused.
I tried unchecking "Send Navigation Events" in my EventSystem object, but then the gamepad won't navigate the buttons and I can only click the mouse.
I have thought of some kind of "game was only unpaused in the last 2 frames" check to ignore all input. That sounds a little goofy/unclean so I'm hoping maybe someone else has a better/cleaner solution.

Also a bit goofy but you might try to directly go by OnGUI, catch and check the Event.current and if you want to consume it call Use on it

I believe the issue lies within the timescale 0 factor, the game is paused but your inputs are not. mostly timeScale 0, doesnt really pause a few functions such as update or fixedupdate, id suggest making a boolean variable isPaused and using an if statement to check if the game is paused or unpaused and hence taking that input.
if (isPaused)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        UnpauseGame();
    }
    return;
}

well the above is a fairly simple use case for it but hopefully that helps you get a better idea of what im saying

That's how I'm unpausing the game in general, and works for the ESC key - but when the unpause comes from the OnClick() of a UI Button, and I've "clicked" that UI Button through the default navigation by pressing the (A) / Submit button on a Gamepad controller, then of course there was no Input.GetKeyDown check on my side ... and that Gamepad button ends up getting picked up by the main game world input controller. Are you saying that if while unpausing I put in a "dummy" check of e.g. the Submit button (and anything else similar) that it would "debounce" them when restarting timescale?

well the dummy check might solve it, but you could also just add a delay in the input through a coroutine, since i'm assuming the (A) press and unpause happen in the same frame thats why its getting taken as an input after unpause. so if you delay its frame, then it shouldn't theoretically cause an issue

Okay excellent unpausing via a 1-frame delayed coroutine seems to do the trick

Thats great, keep it up brian you got this!
